# NodeJS|SailsJS|Waterline: Automatic Model Generation in One-To-Many--To--Many-To-Many Relationships

Tags: javascript, database-design, sails.js, one-to-many, waterline

#### What Type of Relationship is needed below, and How Can I Leverage SailsjS/Waterline to Simplify My Find and Update Queries?

In my app, I have Lists (List-Model), Items (Item-Model), and Provisions (Provision-Model). The app's intention is to manage *Inventory*. As so, Items are discrete -- meaning, there can only be one of the same Item in the Items-collection (`primaryKey` is set on `item.name`). A single List shares a One-To-Many relationship with Items -- *vicariously* through *Provisions*. A Provision is simply a [discrete] Item's details for a given List. In this case, **a Provision is only accessible using both a List-Id and and Item-Id** (`list.id + item.id === provision.compositePrimaryKey`).

My issue is the complexity in dealing with `find` and `update` operations. With an alternative approach, I had just a Many-To-Many relationship between Lists and Items (with Items dominant) -- and this generated an Item upon List-Updates and aggregated Items with `List.find(...).populate('items')`. This was nearly ideal but I needed Provisions in the mix. Now (with the Schema below), the same relationship exists between Lists and Provisions -- List updates and 'populates' generate and aggregate a Provision with the correct `list.id`, but I was expecting Sails/Waterline to generate an Item-Model-Instance because Provision contains a `item: { model: 'item' }` attribute. Here is my current approach:

**Provisions:**

```
//api/models/Provision.js
module.exports = {
    schema: true,
    attributes: {
        ...
        list: { model: 'list' },
        item: { model: 'item' },
        quantity: { type: 'integer' },
        ...
    }
};
```

**Lists:**

```
//api/models/List.js
module.exports = {
    schema: true,
    attributes: {
        ...
        items: { collection: 'provision', via: 'list' },
        ...
    }
};
```

**Items:**

```
//api/models/Item.js
module.exports = {
    schema: true,
    attributes: {
        ...
        name: { type: 'string', primaryKey: true }
        lists: { collection: 'provision', via: 'item' },
        inStock: { type: 'integer' },
        ...
    }
};
```

I would like to generate a Provision -- if only through updating a list -- and have a discrete Item found or created **automatically** -- and hydrate an Item in the Provision-instance when performing a `find` on a List, as each List's Provision will have a `model` link to Item.

How can I do this, or is there a better design which I should employ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Currently `primaryKey` must be `id`, look after sails hooks blueprint at `actionUtil` that primary key must be `id` field yet. So your `Item.js` should be

   ```
   module.exports = {
       schema: true,
       attributes: {
           ...
           // change it's column name if necessary fo your DB scheme
           id: { type: 'string', unique: true, primaryKey: true, columnName: 'name' }
           lists: { collection: 'provision', via: 'item' },
           inStock: { type: 'integer' },
           ...
       }
   };
   ```
2. I don't pretty understand what and how do you want to approach. But using `Lifescycle callbacks` may help you. For example in your statement `I would like to generate a Provision -- if only through updating a list -- and have a discrete Item found or created automatically`, so use `beforeUpdate`, `beforeCreate`, etc. that meets your need.

Comment: Thanks, Andi. This doesn't quite do what I need but it gels with a new approach I'm experimenting with. Cheers!